# parse XML with Python, key value namespaces

Tags: python, xml, wordpress

I have a XML file downloaded from Wordpress that is structured like this:

```
<wp:postmeta>
   <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[country]]></wp:meta_key>
   <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[Germany]]></wp:meta_value>
</wp:postmeta>
```

my goals is to look through the XML file for all the `country` keys and print the value. I'm completely new to the XML library so I'm looking where to take it from here.

```
# load libraries
# importing os to handle directory functions
import os
# import XML handlers
from xml.etree import ElementTree
# importing json to handle structured data saving
import json

# dictonary with namespaces
ns = {'wp:meta_key', 'wp:meta_value'}

tree = ElementTree.parse('/var/www/python/file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# item
for item in root.findall('wp:post_meta', ns):
    print '- ', item.text

print "Finished running"
```

this throws me a error about using wp as a namespace but I'm not sure where to go from here the documentation is unclear to me. Any help is appreciated.
Downvoters please let me know how I can improve my question.

Comment: It seems you are still using Python 2. Does it have to be Python 2?

Comment: @LydiavanDyke I thought it was Python 3, the documentation did imply that. What would the Python 3 alternative be?

Comment: When you can do `print "hello"`, you are using Python 2. Python 3 would respond with SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("hello")?

Comment: Can you please provide a full sample of the XML? For XML parsing the namespace and root element stuff is critical.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know XML, but I can treat it as a string like this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, req, utils
xml = '''
<wp:postmeta>
   <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[country]]></wp:meta_key>
   <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[Germany]]></wp:meta_value>
</wp:postmeta>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
kvs = doc.select('wp:postmeta').selects('wp:meta_key|wp:meta_value').html
print (kvs)
```

Result:

```
['<![CDATA[country]]>', '<![CDATA[Germany]]>']
```